# How to calculate total perimeter of shapes in JavaScript exercise and write proper function

Tags: javascript, function

I was at internship interview, where I couldn't solve one logical exercise. It was too complicate for me. Could you help me and explain how to solve it? (I didn't pass, but I really want to know how to solve it). Exercise is:

"Given an array arr of strings complete the function landPerimeter by calculating the total perimeter of all the islands. Each piece of land will be marked with 'X' while the water fields are represented as 'O'. Consider each tile being a perfect 1 x 1 piece of land. Some examples for better visualization:
['XOOXO',
 'XOOXO',
 'OOOXO',
 'XXOXO',
 'OXOOO']

see image here : https://i.ibb.co/pbDwWSs/pic1.jpg

should return: "Total land perimeter: 24",
while
['XOOO',
 'XOXO',
 'XOXO',
 'OOXX',
 'OOOO']

see image here: https://i.ibb.co/Pcdy8Ct/pic2.jpg

should return: "Total land perimeter: 18"

Kindly ask you to show code example how could I solve this exercise.
Thank you very much!

Comment: please see [ask] and share your attempt before asking

Comment: The algorithm isn't too hard.  Each X is worth 4 units, and you have to remove 2 units for each place two Xs touch, either horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please see this link [find-perimeter-shapes-formed-1s-binary-matrix](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-perimeter-shapes-formed-1s-binary-matrix/). need some small modifications in your case . see below

```
<script>


function numOfNeighbour( mat,  i,  j,rows,cols) 
{ 
    var count = 0;   

    // UP 
    if (i > 0  && mat[i - 1][j]==='X') 
        count++; 

    // LEFT 
    if (j > 0  && mat[i][j - 1]==='X')         
        count++; 

    // DOWN 
    if (i < rows-1  && mat[i + 1][j]==='X')         
        count++; 

    // RIGHT 
    if (j < cols-1 && mat[i][j + 1]==='X')         
        count++; 

    return count; 
} 

function findPerimeter( mat) 
{ 
    var perimeter = 0; 
    var rows=mat.length;
    var cols=mat[0].length;

    // Traversing the matrix and finding ones to 
    // calculate their contribution. 
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
            if (mat[i][j] && mat[i][j]==='X') 
                perimeter += (4 - numOfNeighbour(mat, i ,j,rows,cols)); 

    return perimeter; 
} 

console.log("perimeter of ['XOOXO', 'XOOXO', 'OOOXO', 'XXOXO', 'OXOOO'] is ",findPerimeter(['XOOXO', 'XOOXO', 'OOOXO', 'XXOXO', 'OXOOO'])); //24
console.log("perimeter of ['XOOO', 'XOXO', 'XOXO', 'OOXX', 'OOOO'] is "     ,findPerimeter(['XOOO', 'XOXO', 'XOXO', 'OOXX', 'OOOO'])); //18
</script>
```